# How do I add a new image to the window of an already running game in XNA C# using an if statement in the Update method?

Tags: c#, xna

I am pretty sure something like this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find it.  Anyway, I am making a simple game animation with two moving objects (halloween themed).  The objects bounce off the walls when they hit them, but I also need an image to be displayed when the two objects hit eachother.  I have tried multiple ways, but none of them work.  They either have no effect or raise an error.  Anyway, here is the last thing I tried:

```
 public PumpkinCheckCollisionPumpkin(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (pumpkin1.BoundingBox.Intersects(pumpkin2.BoundingBox))
        {
            pumpkinCollide = True;
            Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

I then tried passing the that bool (which I set to false earlier) to the draw section, but it did not work.  The above method is called within the Update method.
I tried having the draw method invoked in the Update (GameTime gameTime) part, but that didn't work either.  How do I trigger another image to be displayed in addition to what is already is displayed when my two objects collide?  (also, that public method was originally private but made it public so another tactic I tried might work(didn't work)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, **never directly call the `Draw` function**.

In this case, I would set a class level state variable that holds the fact that a collision graphic *should* be drawn on the next draw call, which can then happen.

You erase every time you draw anyways, so even if the call did work correctly, the next `Draw` call (which will happen *really* soon) would erase it. For the same reason, don't unset the flag after the `Draw` call happens, because it will get erased faster than your players can see it. You need to keep it on the screen for some time.

You could do this by setting a variable that holds the time when the flag was set, then checking it against the current time until enough "visible" time has passed. This would then clear the "show collision" flag, and the graphic would no longer draw.

Just let the framework handle the timing of that call, and let the state you set drive what is drawn.

Comment: For clarification, I suggest creating a variable to store the time past sice the first drawing and then, when some time passes, clear the flag.

Comment: @rcdmk Good idea! I added it into the second to last paragraph, do you like that wording?

Comment: What you mean by class level state variable?  And where would the if statement go?  Do you mean as its own class or at the top of the main class?

Comment: @cluemein A **class-level** variable is one that is declared in the class scope. They *typically* are in the "top" of the class, but by no means have to be. The if check for drawing would be in the `Draw` function, the one checking the time would likely be in the `Update` function. I doubt posting your code would help, as the form of the solution is pretty clear right now.

Comment: Actually, what you said there pretty much cleared everything up.  Thanks.  I have trouble with the terminology sometimes.

Comment: @cluemein No problem. Glad I was able to help.